# How to hide redundant top bars in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

Unity was excellent at managing vertical space on the screen by rolling the top bars (the app title bar, its menu bar, and the system's status bar) into one, especially when the application's window was maximised. Gnome 3, at least by default as shipped with Ubuntu 17.10, doesn't quite measure up.

In some instances, like with gnome-terminal, there are three bars, two of which are completely unnecessary and feature the same information over and over. I marked redundant user@host with red boxes.

[image: pointless top bars in Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome 3]

How can I recreate the space frugality Unity would display here?

Comment: Also see this related question: [Auto hiding top panel in 17.10 GNOME 3.26.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968114/auto-hiding-top-panel-in-17-10-gnome-3-26-1)