# Auto hiding top panel in 17.10 GNOME 3.26.1

Tags: gnome-shell

I know Ubuntu 17.10 released only a few days ago, but has someone figured out how to auto-hide the top panel like the dock auto-hides when apps are full screen.

I have followed multiple tutorials online, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the '**Hide top bar**' Gnome Shell Extension.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/

Comment: I installed it via ubuntu software , and it worked, but i can't find it in the start menu

Comment: you have to got to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to enable it if it is not.

Comment: yes, i had to install chrome-gnome-shell , after that i was able to see the extensions in  extensions.gnome.org/local